# On Firefox(98.0) While using geckodriver 0.30.0 move_to_element_with_offset(element,x,y).context_click() coudn't able to find the location on the map

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I tried to open Google Maps with Firefox and click on the coordinate (x,y) on the map. I tried to use ActionChains.move_to_element_with_offset to accomplish this. It works fine in Chromedriver but not in Geckodriver. move_to_element_with_offset(to_element, x, y) does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is an issue with basic moveTo in geckodriver. This is the answer from their github.
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1683

They recommend to use different function to change position in browser.
https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#set-window-rect

Comment: It wasn't clear in the issue whether geckodriver supports Selenium action chains `move_to_element()` or `scroll_to_element()`. Do you have additional documentation stating whether geckodriver supports Selenium action chains, specifically `move_to_element()` and `scroll_to_element()`?